# css input padding is not the same as span-padding

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
echo "<table class='tpT'>";

foreach ($blueprints as $key => $blueprint) {
    echo "<tr><td><span class='neutral'>Slot</span></td><td><input type='text' class='tpI' size='1'><span class='slotTypeOne'>{$blueprint['slot']}</span></td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

in the `blueprints`-array are two elements. Just two names, that I want to display

But the two rows doesn't look alike. They are slightly different.

[image: example]

You see, in the first row, the `input`-field is slightly higher than the red `span`-element. But in the second row, they fit perfectly next to each other. I don't know why. I mean, the two rows should look the same. I think so, at least.

Here is my CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-size: 100%; 
            font-family: Arial;
}

body {
    background: rgba(41, 128, 185,1.0);
    background-attachment: fixed;
}




input.tpI {

    background: rgba(236, 240, 241,.8);
    border: none;
    color: #333;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;

}

table.tpT {
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(50, 50, 50, .6);
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(50, 50, 50, .2);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(50, 50, 50, .2);
    color: #ddd;
    padding: 5px;
}


.tpT td {
    padding: 4px;

}


span.slotTypeOne {
    background: #d35400;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 7px 5.1px 7px;
}

span.neutral {
    color: #333;
    background: rgba(250, 250, 250, 1);
    padding: 5px;
    width: auto;
    border: none;
}
```

I looks different in every browser. But none of them looks perfect. I have no clue why. Because `padding` is 5px. For both.

Any ideas?

Edit:

jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/4wA7r/1

Comment: Is it different from engine to engine (i.e. WebKit vs Gecko) or from browser to browser (i.e. Chrome vs Opera)?

Comment: I'm quite sure the answer can't be in the CSS as both elements are identical so they use the same CSS. So the problem must be in your content. Are you able to reproduce this behaviour in a jsFiddle ?

Comment: It's probably cause of different font renderings, since padding is dependent on the content.

Comment: can use -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; ?

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't support php, I think.  But I can try to write it with javascript.
@AlexWilson look at the top of my CSS

Comment: @Akeno Copying over the relevant, rendered HTML and related CSS to jsfiddle would aid us greatly in helping

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4wA7r/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but **I guess this comes from the line-height**. **Your input and your span don't have the same line-height by default**. So you have to set it to be the same.

```
span.slotTypeOne { 

  background: #d35400;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 7px 5px 7px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: block;
    float: left;

}
input.tpI {

    background: rgba(236, 240, 241,.8);
    border: none;
    color: #333;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

As you can see, I had to set those elements to display: block, as they couldn't stay inline element (or we couldn't adjust the "inner line-height").

This works here : http://jsfiddle.net/4wA7r/4/

Comment: `input` tags have always behaved in strange ways for me. Setting `line-height` is a good approach.

Comment: Sure, each browser as its own styles for inputs... And it can be really different.